# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

"String was not recognized as a valid `DateTime`" error was occurred when I tried to convert a string to `DateTime`.

I stored the current date using `getDate()` method into my DB. And it was set as `DateTime`. I retrieved it and display in a `DetailsView`. And later I retrieve from the `DetailsView` and set on a label.

```
Label ForgotDatelbl = new Label();
ForgotDatelbl = (Label)DetailsView2.FindControl("ForgotPwLabel");

DateTime ForgotDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ForgotDatelbl.ToString(),
      "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null); //here is the error

if (DateTime.Now < ForgotDate.AddMinutes(3)) { 
}
```

Source Error:

```
Line 28:             DateTime ForgotDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ForgotDatelbl.ToString(),"d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
Line 29: 
Line 30:             if (DateTime.Now < ForgotDate.AddMinutes(3))
```

and in my database the time was like this - `20/7/2012 7:42:19 PM`

**EDIT**

```
IFormatProvider theCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
DateTime ForgotDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ForgotDatelbl.ToString(), "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", theCultureInfo);
```

However, error still remain..

Comment: It's not possible to get that error when converting from DateTime to String. You get the error when you try to convert from String to DateTime.

Comment: Are you sure you know the exact format of the date? I guess you are not, else you wouldnt be getting this kind of error!

Comment: I had changed it to dd/MM/yyyy and dd/m/yyyy, but problem still persist

Comment: Please have a look at my answer, think that solves the problem

Comment: Perhaps you parse with the wrong culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the format with only 1h specifier:

```
//20/7/2012 7:42:19 PM
"dd/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
```

Comment: And no need for custom culture, invariant will do. Also, single `d` may be necessary instead of `dd`;

Answer (score 0):

use `Culture` in overload method

Comment: Hi, I had amended my code 
IFormatProvider theCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
            DateTime ForgotDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ForgotDatelbl.ToString(), "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", theCultureInfo);

but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following

```
string dateString = "20/7/2012 7:42:19 PM";

//can be this in your case: string dateLabel = ForgotDatelbl.Text;

var culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
var date = DateTime.Parse(dateString, culture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

This parses an exact match of what you want.